# Neo4J 2.0 M4 - Create unique node with label and properties

Tags: cypher, label, neo4j

I was wondering why such a Cypher statement was currently not possible with the latest milestone:

```
CREATE UNIQUE (n:Person { name : 'Andres' , title : 'Developer' })
```

Drop `UNIQUE` and it will just work.
Any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the `MERGE` keyword with neo4j 2.0. The `CREATE UNIQUE` will be replaced by that. If no matching node exists a new one will be created. Otherwise the already existing one is used. Please have a look at http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/05/new-milestone-release-neo4j-200-m03.html